# Google Search Results Integration (Chrome Extension)

Tags: app, search, chrome-extensions

### Screenshots

[image: before]
[image: after]

### About

Google Chrome Extension that adds a new tab to StackOverflow search results that uses Google magic formula for relevance.

It does this by opening Google search in a background tab and reading its results, then converting them to StackOverflow format. You will see a new tab popping up for a moment, but I think it is a small price to pay for good quality search.

Currently works only on the main SO site.

Number of results currently depends on your search settings for google.com site (10 in case if Instant Search is enabled, 50 otherwise, but usually even 10 is more than enough).

#### Download

[Download from Google WebStore](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/fghgcacpbflnffcpcakindbhdmmaffdk) (free)

#### Platform

Google Chrome Extension

#### Changelog

**0.2** (May 16, 2011):

- fixed crash on some searches
- added link to google site

Comment: you might try searching within a tag, e.g.  http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjavascript%5D+date+format ; I think the issue with the search pictured is the use of "js" which is kind of meaningless

Comment: @Jeff I know it is probably not the the most correct search request, but that's where Google shines - in guessing what you really wanted.  I don't have anything against SO search, it is as good is it gets (and I understand how hard it was to implement it), but it's just not possible to beat Google on its territory.